# Wagtail tags. Get tags as queryset

Tags: wagtail

I'm trying to get tags as a queryset to loop through and get another BlogPost that has the same tags, but I get

```
def get_related_content(self):
    related_content = []
    if self.tags:
        for tag in self.tags:
            related_content += BlogDetailPage.objects.live().filter(tags__name=tag)
            related_content += OfferDescription.objects.live().filter(tags__name=tag)
    else:
        return related_content
```

I get this error:

> '_ClusterTaggableManager' object is not iterable

I have also tried to use the django-taggit `get_query_set()` method, but it doesn't work, seems not to be included in the wagtail.

```
def get_related_content(self):
    related_content = []
    if self.tags:
        for tag in self.tags.get_query_set():
            related_content += BlogDetailPage.objects.live().filter(tags__name=tag)
            related_content += OfferDescription.objects.live().filter(tags__name=tag)
    else:
        return related_content
```

---

```
'_ClusterTaggableManager' object has no attribute 'get_query_set'
```

How can I loop over all `self.tags` and get other page models that use similar tags?

My Models:

```
class OfferDescriptionPageTag(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = ParentalKey('OfferDescription', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tagged_items')

class OfferDescription(Page):

    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=OfferDescriptionPageTag, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example, try `for tag in self.tags.all():`.

Your line `if self.tags` won't help, because the tags relationship is a manager, not a queryset, and will always evaluate to `True`. You could test `if self.tags.exists()`.

In your second code example, the method should be `.get_queryset()`. See https://github.com/wagtail/django-modelcluster/blob/master/modelcluster/contrib/taggit.py#L26.

Comment: Good o. Just for completeness, this works as in my next comment, because `.tags` is a manager, similar to the usual default manager `MyModel.objects`. To get a queryset from it, proceed as per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects